# Use classes based on multiple columns in text classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification

I am working on a text classification problem for which I cant think of or find a solution. Essentially I am classifying a private complaint database which has custom categories per municipality this because some municipalities have other issues than others.

Example:

```
Mun.                Issue                                                 Class
London              Street lights are off                                 Street-lighting
New York            Street lights are off                                 lighting
```

As you can see, I want to classify the issue based on the municipality, thus based on the first column select only the specific categories of that municipality and then choose the one which is classified by the issue. Currently I created superclasses which contains similar classes but now I want to be more specific. I have a big dataset and every municipality has around 10 classes.

Comment: It would be very useful to know more things about your problem. Cardilanity of your label set (number of municipalities x number of classes per municipality), samples per label, samples per municipality... On a general note, I would say classifiing the superclass and then post-proccess with rules the result to undo the superclass seems a very simple and nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal classification algorithm with a neural net. steps would be:
1. Create the corpus into One hot vector
2. Train the neural network as multiclass classification

I think any normal neural network with a sufficient number of neurons can provide the results.